# Update product stock with observer Magento 2

Tags: stock, programmatically

right now I need to have a sincronization between my magento products and a third party software, lets call it X, X stores all the products info, my goal is to use a observer to update a single product stock on page load, so when it loads the page it will make sure to have the stock update to prevent errors between the two databases stocks.

Any idea is welcome.

PD : Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to put conditions at 3 places, 1st when product page loads, 2nd when adding to cart and 3rd when placing order.